# how do I run ssh on rpi

Tags: raspbian

X: user not authorized to run the x server, aborting is the response to startx in terminal.

My rpi boots to the gui, and not the terminal with login prompt.

I am always the $ user,

Comment: Are you trying to run startx from an SSH connection?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to allow a little more clarity on what you are trying to accomplish? Your title asks how to run ssh, but your question asks about X. Are you trying to run X over an ssh session, start an ssh session or...?

Answer (score 1):

William,

On Windows system, you can use [Putty](http://www.putty.org) which is a reference on the domain.
In the Host Name input, enter:

> pi@your_pi_ip_address

On a Linux host, you can use the following command.

```
ssh pi@your_pi_ip_address -p 22
```

Jeff